# Dynamic dropdown jQuery inline error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, drop-down-menu

I am trying t create dynamic dropdown using a value of array but values are appending inline in `option`

```html
<body onload="getdata()">
  <select class="form-control"   id="focusedinput" name="sBranchName"  required>
    <option name="sBranchName" id="branch_list" ></option>
  </select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>
function getdata () {
 var data =['rajkot','surat','delhi']
 var mySelect = $('#branch_list'); 
   for(let value of data){
    console.log(value)
       mySelect.append("<option>" + value + "</option>")
    }
};
</script>
</body>
```

Can anyone suggest the proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this line:

`mySelect.append("<option>" + value + "<option>")`

You're missing a `/`.

You're also appending to the `option` rather than to the `select`. Try selecting the `select` instead:

`$('#focusedinput').append("<option>" + value + "</option>")`

```js
function getdata() {
  const data = ['rajkot', 'surat', 'delhi']
  const mySelect = $('#focusedinput');
  data.forEach((value) => {
    mySelect.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
  });
}

getdata();
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="focusedinput" name="sBranchName" required>
  <option name="sBranchName" id="branch_list" ></option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Made a live snippet, works for me. (though your initial `option` is still blank, don't know what you want to do with that)